# Eliminate rows based on datetime when date is duplicate but time isn't

Tags: r, datetime

I have a dataframe with categories and datetime stamps:

```
category <- c('a', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a')
date_time <- c('2017-05-12 21:29:00', '2017-05-12 21:28:32', '2017-08-22 00:00:00', '2017-07-12 00:00:00', '2017-05-26 18:47:23', '2017-05-12 21:33:06')

data <- data.frame(category, date_time) %>%
  mutate(date_time = ymd_hms(date_time, tz="UTC"),
         date = as.Date(date_time, format = ('%Y-%m-%d')))
```

which results in

```
  category            date_time        date
1        a  2017-05-12 21:29:00  2017-05-12
2        a  2017-05-12 21:28:32  2017-05-12
3        c  2017-08-22 00:00:00  2017-08-22
4        b  2017-07-12 00:00:00  2017-07-12
5        a  2017-05-26 18:47:23  2017-05-26
6        a  2017-05-12 21:33:06  2017-05-12
```

There are 4 instances of category A, 3 of which happen at different times on the same day (2017-05-12).

I need to 'de-dup' the data such that only one instance of each category per day is maintained. I have tried:

```
data %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  slice(which.min(date_time))
```

which results in

```
  category            date_time        date
1        a  2017-05-12 21:28:32  2017-05-12
2        c  2017-08-22 00:00:00  2017-08-22
3        b  2017-07-12 00:00:00  2017-07-12
```

but I need to maintain the category A instance on 2017-05-26--so final df would be:

```
  category            date_time        date
1        a  2017-05-12 21:28:32  2017-05-12
2        c  2017-08-22 00:00:00  2017-08-22
3        b  2017-07-12 00:00:00  2017-07-12
4        a  2017-05-26 18:47:23  2017-05-26
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try grouping by both category and date and then filtering

```
data %>%
  group_by(category, date) %>%
  filter(date_time == min(date_time))
```

Comment: I was fiddling with trying to do that in an extra step by extracting time... duh. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
data[which(data$category == 'a'),]$date[which(duplicated(data[which(data$category == 'a'),]$date) == TRUE)]
```

This will tell you which dates are duplicated for that category. You can then create a duplicate check so you can view the entries duplicated

```
duplicate_check <- data[which(data$date == '2017-05-12' & data$category == 'a'),]
```

Then remove based on which observation you want to keep. You can remove them using the standard `c()` function and using the row numbers. The step you create duplicate_check in will retain the row numbers and you just need to specify which rows you want to drop.

```
data <- data[-c(1,6),] #removing the rows numbered 1 and 6
```

You only have to write the first step once for each category and it will show you whenever there is duplicated data for that category every time, even as your data grows.
I get this in return

```
category   date_time         date
a     2017-05-12 21:28:32    2017-05-12
c     2017-08-22 00:00:00    2017-08-22
b     2017-07-12 00:00:00    2017-07-12
a     2017-05-26 18:47:23    2017-05-26
```